# Creating VM in existing Vnet. Cant see existing Vnet

Tags: networking, azure

I am trying to create Vm in existing resource Group where I already have vnet in that resource group and also NIC in that vnet.

However, when trying to create VM on the networking blade azure does not show existing Vnet, hence cant select it. Instead it its insists on creating new Vnet and NIC for machine

Puzzled. Any thoughts?

Comment: select "Resource manager" as distribution model to be able to select the correct VNET. Also it may be related to the version. This Microsoft website described the information https://github.com/Azure/migAz/issues/145

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you create new VM in the same region where your VNET is located.